# How to draw rectangle around map area in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a map of the Northern Hemisphere centered around North America. I would like to draw a red rectangle around the USA (this is part of an inset map) however, I can not seem to get `geom_rect` to draw the rectangle. Any ideas?

Code to make map:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggspatial)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)

world <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = "medium",
                                     returnclass = "sf")

ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
```

This is the code I'm trying to use to get the red rectangle around the USA which is not working:

```
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = -132, xmax = -69, ymin = 23, ymax = 49), color = "red", inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

The ideal map would look something like this [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add one more layer of geom_sf and mention its own co-ordinates like this:

```
a <- st_as_sf(data.frame(plot_id = 1, lat = -100, long = 36), 
              coords = c("lat", "long"), crs = 4326)

ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = a, shape = 0, size = 35, color = "red", stroke = 2) +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
```

You can change the shape as required

[image]

Comment: And removing geom_rect()

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that your box is defined in terms of longitude and latitude, but the projection you use is LAEA [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btP4Z.png). You can solve the problem by changing your projection to lon/lat:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = -132, xmax = -69, ymin = 23, ymax = 49), color = "red", fill = NA)  +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=lonlat +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
```

[image]

If you need your map to be in LAEA, you need to describe your box in these terms:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = -2464417, xmax = 2574417, ymin = -3064417, ymax = 1264417), color = "red", fill = NA)  +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
```

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btP4Z.png) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_azimuthal_equal-area_projection